# Why is the default value of spark.memory.fraction so low?

Tags: apache-spark

From the [Spark configuration docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management), we understand the following about the `spark.memory.fraction` configuration parameter:

> Fraction of (heap space - 300MB) used for execution and storage. The lower this is, the more frequently spills and cached data eviction occur. The purpose of this config is to set aside memory for internal metadata, user data structures, and imprecise size estimation in the case of sparse, unusually large records. Leaving this at the default value is recommended.

The default value for this configuration parameter is 0.6 at the time of writing this question. This means that for an executor with, for example, 32GB of heap space and the default configurations we have:

- `300MB` of reserved space (a hardcoded value on [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0e2d604fd33c8236cfa8ae243eeaec42d3176a06/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/memory/UnifiedMemoryManager.scala#L198) line)
- `(32GB - 300MB) * 0.6 = 19481MB` of shared memory for execution + storage
- `(32GB - 300MB) * 0.4 = 12987MB` of user memory

This "user memory" is (according to the [docs](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/tuning.md#memory-management-overview)) used for the following:

> The rest of the space (40%) is reserved for user data structures, internal metadata in Spark, and safeguarding against OOM errors in the case of sparse and unusually large records.

On an executor with 32GB of heap space, we're allocating 12,7GB of memory for this, which feels rather large!

Do these *user data structures/internal metadata/safeguarding against OOM errors* really need that much space? Are there some striking examples of user memory usage which illustrate the need of this big of a user memory region?

Answer (score 6):

I did some research and imo its 0.6 not to ensure enough memory for user memory but to ensure that execution + storage can fit into old gen region of jvm

Here i found something interesting: [Spark tuning](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/tuning.html)

> The tenured generation size is controlled by the JVM’s NewRatio
> parameter, which defaults to 2, meaning that the tenured generation is
> 2 times the size of the new generation (the rest of the heap). So, by
> default, the tenured generation occupies 2/3 or about 0.66 of the
> heap. A value of 0.6 for spark.memory.fraction keeps storage and
> execution memory within the old generation with room to spare. If
> spark.memory.fraction is increased to, say, 0.8, then NewRatio may
> have to increase to 6 or more.

So by default in OpenJvm this ratio is set to 2 so you have 0,66% for old-gen, they choose to use 0,6 to have small margin

I found that in version 1.6 this was changed to 0,75 and it was causing some issues, here is [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15796)

In the description you will find sample code which is adding records to cache just to use whole memory reserved for exeution + storage. With storage + execution set to higher amount than old gen overhead for gc was really high and code which was executed on older version (with this setting equal to 0.6) was 6 time faster (40-50 sec vs 6 min)

There was discussion and community decided to roll it back to 0.6 in Spark 2.0, here is [PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13618/files) with changes

I think that if you want to increase performance a little bit, you can try to change it up to 0.66 but if you want to have more memory for execution+storageyou need to also adjust your jvm and change old/new ratio as well otherwise you may face performance issues

Comment: That's extremely interesting info! I definitely learned something from this, so you're getting a big upvote. There is one worrying thing about this though, does this mean that the documentation is wrong/incomplete? As I quoted in my original question, the docs state that this 40% is for whatever data structures etc. If what you're saying is correct (which honestly it sounds like a great theory) I think the docs should contain this information as well. Let's see if there are some other interesting pieces of info coming through. Thanks a bunch anyway!